How to start ggplot title above y-axis labels?
Sometimes my y-axis labels are long and this leads the title to begin too far to the right. How can I start my ggplot title above the y-axis labels rather than start right of the y-axis labels?
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
    rownames_to_column('model') |> 
    ggplot(aes(x=model, y = mpg)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = 'How can I start this title in the upper left corner above the model labels?')



Add in this function scale_y_discrete(position='right') like this
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  rownames_to_column('model') |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=model, y = mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = 'How can I start this title in the upper left corner above the model labels?')+
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right")

